# adding a little swirl icon when loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im sure this is completely simple , infact i'm sure i have already seen the code for this somewhere , i just cant remember for the life of me where.

all i want to do is add the little swirl image thing whilst loading. can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a UIActivityIndicatorView

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,140,50,50)];
[spinner startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner release];
```

You will probably want to hold on to a pointer to it though so you can remove it later.

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking for standard `UIActivityIndicatorView` control.